# Randomized Algorithm for finding maximum in a sequence

Tags: pr.probability, algorithms

I read it on some website (which I do not remember now) that in a sequence of length $n$, to find the maximum value (with high probability) one only needs to generate a constant multiple of $\log(n)$ random numbers from the sequence. I could not find any reference for this.

My question: Is this true? If so, what is the exact statement in terms of the probability bound? If not $\log n$ number of samples, is there any randomized algorithm that requires far less than $n$ samples and outputs a number provably larger than the maximum with a specified probability.

I was able to prove the following (which is simple): suppose the sequence is $x_1, \ldots, x_N$. Let $x_{(\beta N)}$ denote the $\beta N$-th largest value of the sequence. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ denote iid uniform random variables uniform on the sequence. Then for any $\beta\in(0, 1)$ and $n\ge 1$,

$\mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} > x_{(\beta N)}) = 1 - \beta^n.$

For this probability to be say $0.99$, we need $n \ge \log(100)/\log(1/\beta)$. If $\beta = 1 - k/N$ for some $k$ then $\beta N = N - k$ and so, $x_{(\beta N)}$ represents the $(N - k)$-th largest value and for this case $n \ge N\log(100)/k$. This implies that the number of random samples required is of the order $N$.

Comment: I'm not clear about the question. Are you looking for a generalization of the result you proved to the case where $\{X_i\}$ are not identically distributed (but presumably still independent)?

Comment: If you can only look at individual elements, you can't find the max element with high prob using less than $\Theta(n)$ looks.  Because: the max element might be anywhere. Three other things you might be recalling: (1) the maximum of a unimodal sequence can be found in $O(\log n)$ looks, (2) a local maximum (number not smaller than the number on either side) can be found in $O(\log n)$ looks, (3) Carlo's answer, which uses all the elements but performs $O(\log^2 n)$ tests which are to evaluate a multivariable polynomial with arguments from the sequence and compare it to 0.

Answer (score 6):

[image]
[A Randomized Algorithm for Finding Maximum with $O(\log^2 n)$ Polynomial Tests](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.4993&rep=rep1&type=pdf), H.F. Ting and A.C. Yao (1994)